# Using `$$...$$` vs`\[...\]`

Tags: math-mode

In order to center stuff in math mode, we can use either `$$...$$` or `\[...\]`.  Is there an OBJECTIVE reason as to why one is better than the other?

Answer (score 2):

From the [l2tabu document](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) (section 1.6):

> **1.6 Separating maths formulae from continuous text using $$...$$**
>
> Please don’t do this! $$...$$ is a Plain TEX command. It will modify
>   vertical spacing within formulae, rendering them inconsistent. This is
>   why it should be avoided in LATEX (see section 3.3 on page 15; note
>   the warning concerning displaymath along with the amsmath.sty
>   package). What’s more, class option fleqn won’t work any more.
>   Replace: $$...$$ by \[...\]
>
> or
>
> \begin{displaymath}
>
> ...
>
> \end{displaymath}

So assuming you consider a preference for consistency objectively justified, yes, there is an objective reason to use one rather than the other.

Comment: OK, thanks.  One question though, what does it mean by "It will modify vertical spacing within formulae"?

Comment: @Mathematician See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854/39222 which is much better than the top rated answer to the original of your question. (And much better than my semi-answer here.)